# How can i add the values in the firebase database and store the total

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
  reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                   double total = 0;

                    for( DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        incomeinfo incomeinfo = ds.getValue(incomeinfo.class);
                        double amount = Double.valueOf(incomeinfo.getAmount());
                        total = total + amount;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

*this is my reference code for the adding the total of amount*

```
public class incomeinfo {

    public String payeename;
    public double amount;
    public String status;
    public String mod;
    public double total;

    public String getPayeename() {
        return payeename;
    }

    public void setPayeename(String payeename) {
        this.payeename = payeename;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMod() {
        return mod;
    }

    public void setMod(String mod) {
        this.mod = mod;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public incomeinfo(String payeename, double amount, String status, String mod, double total) {
        this.payeename = payeename;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.status = status;
        this.mod = mod;
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

*My incomeinfo class to store the data to firebase*

[firebase overview need to add the amount sum in all the different groups click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT62e.png)

*some one please help me to add the sum of all the amounts.*

Comment: do you need just to count a sum?  you sure that you need to use firebase?

Comment: yes the data need to be stored for months so i prefered firebase

Comment: How is `reference` defined? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

after your for-each loop you have to go through the database again and set field "total" by value you just counted before and save every instance of incomeinfo to you DB
something like this

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    incomeinfo incomeinfo = ds.getValue(incomeinfo.class);
                    incomeinfo.setTotal(total);
                    dbHelper.saveIncomeinfo(incomeinfo);
                }
```

Comment: bro help me out with use of firebase

Comment: do you have dbHelper? how can you save data to your db?

Comment: i store it through databasereference in firebase realtime database

Comment: first of all you need to add default constructor in your class incomeinfo   also check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write